# Unable to update composer, getting Deprecation Notice

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Recently I wanted to add a new package (laravel-dompdf) in Laravel using composer. But it is throwing some Deprecated Notice. Initially I used composer for YII2 and was perfectly working.

Here is the screen short:
[image]

Comment: Try  : composer self-update  or install composer again

Comment: when i try for composer self-update, it says:  You are already using composer version 395d115d9b40d799dadc9f4c5b73cd54820112e3.

Comment: try to remove configuration

Comment: @shalini yes I have made a fresh installation but still getting the same message.

Answer (score 5):

Just delete folder 'vendor' and file 'composer.lock'. 
Then 'composer global update'

IT WORKS.